# Spring 3.2 form errors long restful URLs

Tags: java, forms, spring, spring-mvc

Think this is an easy one but don't know how to handle it.

I have a form like this.

```
    <c:url value="edit" var="editprofileUrl" />
    <form:form class="form" id="signup" action="${editprofileUrl}" method="post" modelAttribute="editProfileForm">
        <div class="formInfo">
            <s:bind path="*">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${status.error}">
                        <div class="text-danger">Unable to change profile. Please fix the errors below and resubmit.</div>
                    </c:when>
                </c:choose>
            </s:bind>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First name</label>
            <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="text-danger" />
            <form:input class="form-control" path="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="text-danger" />
            <form:input class="form-control" id="last-name" path="lastName" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save profile</button>
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

And the java form like this:

```
public class EditProfileForm {

    @NotEmpty
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

And a controller like this:

```
@Controller
@Transactional
public class EditProfileController {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editProfile(@PathVariable String username, Principal currentUser, @Valid EditProfileForm form, BindingResult formBinding) {
        if (formBinding.hasErrors()) {
            return null;
        }

        Account user = entityManager.find(Account.class, currentUser.getName());
        user.setFirstName(form.getFirstName());
        user.setLastName(form.getLastName());
        entityManager.persist(user);

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{username}/edit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editProfileForm(@PathVariable String username, Principal currentUser, WebRequest request, Model model) {

        Account account = entityManager.find(Account.class, username);

        if (account != null) {
            model.addAttribute("account", account);
        }

        EditProfileForm form = new EditProfileForm();
        form.setFirstName(account.getFirstName());
        form.setLastName(account.getLastName());

        return new ModelAndView("editprofile", "editProfileForm", form);
    }
}
```

Everything works good besides when I don't fill in anything in one of the fields and it should give an error.

Something breaks in this code snippet:

```
if (formBinding.hasErrors()) {
    return null;
}
```

Instead of returning the same page again with the errors it looks for a view that does not exist:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /project/WEB-INF/views/users/nilsi/edit.jsp
```

How do I return the same view again with the errors? Usually it works when i have a shorter `@RequestMapping` like `/signup`.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: Don't you want to return "editprofile" instead of null, to indicate that it should show the edit view again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event of binding errors, return the name of the form view again so that the user can correct the errors.

```
if (formBinding.hasErrors()) {
    return "editprofile";
}
```

If you return null, Spring tries to guess a view name by looking at the url. Since your url ends with ".../edit", it tries to load edit.jsp.

Comment: OMG, it worked, I feel stupid :D Tried it before but might had a typo. Thanks!